# BigQuery - How to modify sample Github java sample program(LoadDataCsvSample.java) to display errors

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm refering to [LoadDataCSVSample.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/samples/LoadDataCsvSample.java) program, I am able to load CSV data into BigQuery when I define proper schema and CSV data. But when I provide incorrect data, I receive message as "Load is Done!" but the data is not loaded and I am not able to see the errors. How to modify this sample program to capture errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this example is missing analyzing errors after job is completed ("Load Is Done").
Jobs are either in PENDING or RUNNING or DONE state.
The fact that job is DONE doesn't tell yet if it is succeeded or failed

To know this - you should use [jobId](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#jobReference.jobId) and then use [Jobs: get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get) to get [status.state](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#status.state) of the job. Here you can see if job completed (DONE) or not yet (PENDING or RUNNING), so do this till it is completed and when it is - you can look into [status.errorResult](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#status.errorResult) for last error or into [status.errors](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#status.errors) for all errors encountered during the running of the job

Comment: If you really want to learn something, you should take the answer and read all links and examples in them and try to come up with code by yourself. Sure you will still have something that you will need help with - so you will ask next SPECIFIC question. In this case I will be more than hAppy to help more. From how I see your initial question - I already answered it.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. I have posted the code using your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Mikhail's answer, here is the code,

```
    JobReference jobRef = insert.execute().getJobReference();
    System.out.println("Job ID is: " + jobRef.getJobId());

    Boolean Run_Status = true;
    while (Run_Status) {
        Job pollJob = bigquery.jobs().get(projectId, jobRef.getJobId()).execute();
        System.out.println("Job status: " + pollJob.getStatus().getState());
        if (pollJob.getStatus().getState().equals("DONE")) {
            System.out.println(pollJob.getStatus().getErrors());
            Run_Status = false;
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```